# Whether to use second or third conditional sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, conditional-constructions, subjunctives

I have read about conditional sentences over [here](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/conditional-sentences/), now I have to form a conditional sentence but I am not sure whether it should be in second or third conditional sentence.

Do either of the following correctly express the past conditional?

> If he were a supporter of Modi/Trump/ABC, would you have supported
>   him?
>
> If he had been a supporter of Modi/Trump/ABC, would you have supported
>   him?

Comment: Your first sentence is ungrammatical as written. It should be *If he **were** a supporter of Modi/Trump/ABC, would you **support** him?* With that change, both sentences are fine—although they mean different things.

Comment: @JasonBassford Thank you for your reply. But `If he were a supporter of Modi/Trump/ABC, would you support him?` indicates present/future possibility/condition... what I want to express is past, a past hypothetical possibility/condition...

Comment: You already said that in your *second* sentence: *If he **had been** a supporter of Modi/Trump/ABC, would you **have supported** him?* If that's all you had meant, then I don't understand the presence of the first sentence.

Comment: @JasonBassford Oh I see. This is what I wanted to confirm that whether first or second is correct for what I want to express. Please correct me/highlight if English of my comments are not correct. I am on learning path so any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I rephrased your question to avoid the confusion I had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *past* conditional is expressed in your second sentence.

---

The *present* conditional would be:

> If he **were** a supporter of Modi/Trump/ABC, would you **support** him?

So, your first sentence is a hybrid of past and present. It doesn't correctly express either tense.